# Invoke lambda function from a cloudformation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

Am new to cloudformation template in json.

Here is my issue

I created an Ontap cluster using cloudformation template. Am looking to update ontapclusterpassword using secrets manager in the same cloudformation and so am invoking lambda function from a different stack. Am exporting ontapclusterid(fsxid) so that I could use it in the lambda function when updating the password

The lambda function is created in a different stack and I used a dependency as ontapcluster as I wanted this lambda function to update the password based on the ontapclusterid(fsxid) created from the ontap cluster stack.

Am not sure what is the right way to do it.

Although am exporting the fsxid and trying to import it, I get the error when deploying lambda function first as it says it has nothing to import.

My intent is to update ontapcluster password during ontap cluster creation itself using lambda function. However, since am adding a dependency as ontapcluster and importing value of fsxid while creating lambda function I believe am not doing it right.

Could you please guide what should be my approach.

Answer (score 0):

You need to develop a [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) for that. Your resource would be in the form of your lambda function.